# Make Spring's @RequestBody annotation return a custom response on-fail

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a controller as follows:

```
public void createEntity(@Valid @RequestBody final MyEntity myEntity) {}
```

However, when the object transformation fails, the API automatically returns a `400` with the Java stack trace. How can I modify this on-failure response? (I wish to change or remove the response message).

Comment: check `@ExceptionHandler` `@ControllerAdvice`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to do this with an `@ExceptionHandler` annotation

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void createEntity(@Valid @RequestBody final MyEntity myEntity) {
        //
    }


    @ControllerAdvice
    public class RestEndpointExceptionHandler { 

        @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
        public ResponseEntity<Object> handleNotValidExceptionException(HttpServletRequest req, MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
          Object customException = "Validation failed";
          return new ResponseEntity<Object>(customException, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

    }
}
```

I pushed the code in [here](https://github.com/gjeanmart/stackexchange/tree/master/51722296-make-springs-requestbody-annotation-return-a-custom-response-on-fail)

Comment: is it possible to move the `RestEndpointExceptionHandler` to a new class and share it between controllers?

Comment: Yeah it's definitely possible and it'll automatically apply to all the controllers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@ExceptionHandler` with `@ResponseStatus` and leave handler empty so that only Status Code is returned back.

```
@ExceptionHandler(EmptyResultDataAccessException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public void notFoundException() {
}
```